# Green's Theorem special application

Tags: vectors, vector-fields, greens-theorem

If I want to evaluate the flux  of a vector field over an unfinished square (basically over three sides of a square), instead of parametrezing the 3 sides and computing the flux 3 times, can I use Green's theorem over the full square and subtract from it the flux over the line integral of the side that was not available before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After re-reading I think you seem to suggest
\begin{align}
\int\limits_\sqsubset A \cdot dr
&= 
\int\limits_{\square = \partial S} A \cdot dr - 
\int\limits_{.\vert} A \cdot dr \\
&= 
\int\limits_S\text{curl } A  \cdot dS - 
\int\limits_{.\vert} A \cdot dr \\
&= 
\int\limits_S (\partial_1 A_2 - \partial_2 A_1) 
\lVert dS \rVert- 
\int\limits_{.\vert} A \cdot dr \\
\end{align}
where we extended to three dimensions in between by giving the square surface a unit normal in positive 3-direction: $S = \lVert S \rVert  e_3$
and using Kelvin-Stokes instead of Green.

Comment: I don't really understand your answer. Why do I need to find a vector potential A?

Comment: Let me rephrase maybe I didn't explain myself very well:

Imagine A(1,-1), B(1,1), C(-1,1), D(-1,-1) 4 vertices of the square ABCD. Now I want the flux over the curve that goes from A to B, B to C and C to D.

Can I use Green's Theorem over ABCD and subtract from that the flux over CD?

Comment: For the flux-divergence or normal form Green's Theorem, it relates the partial derivative of M with respect to x (i component of vector field) with partial derivative of N with respect to y (j component of vector field) which we add and take the integral over the region formed by the curves.

Comment: Ok it seems we have a mismatch of dimensions. I gave the 3D version.

Comment: So is this technique of application correct?

Edit: Oh I see. For now we are only using it in 2 dimensions.